# JavaFx graphics window scaling issue

Tags: java, javafx

I have a problem: when the program is running, the scaling of the chart window is not active. When the window is resized, the chart and other window elements are not scaled

Tell me what to add to fix the problem?

source:

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Button button = new Button();   //Создание кнопки
        button.setText("Начать");  //Создание надписи на кнопке
        button.setPrefSize(150,30);  // Размер кнопки
        button.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);  // Положение кнопки на экране
        button.setTranslateY(75);  //Перемещение кнопки по оси Y
        button.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 20)); //Параметры шрифта и размер шрифта

        Label label1 = new Label("Верзьера Аньези"); // Создание текста
        label1.setPrefSize(580, 225); // Размер текста
        label1.setLayoutX(100); // Положение текста в рамках Label по оси Х
        label1.setLayoutY(100); // Положение текста в рамках Label по оси Y
        label1.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER); // Положение текста на экране
        label1.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 20)); // Параметры шрифта и размер шрифта


        Label label2 = new Label("Введите диаметр а (Рек. 2):"); // Создание текста
        label2.setPrefSize(580, 100); // Размер текста
        label2.setLayoutX(100); // Положение текста в рамках Label по оси Х
        label2.setLayoutY(100); // Положение текста в рамках Label по оси Y
        label2.setTranslateY(-25); // Положение текста по оси Х на экране
        label2.setTranslateX(40); // Положение текста по оси Y на экране
        label2.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT); // Положение текста на экране
        label2.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 12)); // Параметры шрифта и размер шрифта

        Label label3 = new Label("Интервал осей (X/Y):"); // Создание текста
        label3.setPrefSize(580, 100); // Размер текста
        label3.setLayoutX(100); // Положение текста в рамках Label по оси Х
        label3.setLayoutY(100); // Положение текста в рамках Label по оси Y
        label3.setTranslateY(6); // Положение текста по оси Х на экране
        label3.setTranslateX(30); // Положение текста по оси Y на экране
        label3.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT); // Положение текста на экране
        label3.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 12)); // Параметры шрифта и размер шрифта


        TextField txtf = new TextField(); // Создание поля ввода
        txtf.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT); // Положение поля ввода на экране
        txtf.setTranslateY(-65); // Положение поля ввода по оси Х на экране
        txtf.setTranslateX(60); // Положение поля ввода по оси Y на экране
        txtf.setMaxWidth(75); // Максимальное количество значений
        txtf.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 15)); // Параметры шрифта и размер шрифта

        TextField txtxLow = new TextField(); // Создание поля ввода
        txtxLow.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT); // Положение поля ввода на экране
        txtxLow.setTranslateY(-35); // Положение поля ввода по оси Х на экране
        txtxLow.setTranslateX(20); // Положение поля ввода по оси Y на экране
        txtxLow.setMaxWidth(75); // Максимальное количество значений
        txtxLow.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 15)); // Параметры шрифта и размер шрифта

        TextField txtxHi = new TextField(); // Создание поля ввода
        txtxHi.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT); // Положение поля ввода на экране
        txtxHi.setTranslateY(-35); // Положение поля ввода по оси Х на экране
        txtxHi.setTranslateX(100); // Положение поля ввода по оси Y на экране
        txtxHi.setMaxWidth(75); // Максимальное количество значений
        txtxHi.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 15)); // Параметры шрифта и размер шрифта




        txtf.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue,
                                String newValue) {                                       // Ограничение ввода значений, разрешены только цифры и знак -
                if (!newValue.matches("|[-+]?|[-+]?\\d+\\.?|[-+]?\\d+\\.?\\d+")){
                    txtf.setText(oldValue);
                }
            }
        });

        txtxLow.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue,
                                String newValue) {
                if (!newValue.matches("|[-+]?|[-+]?\\d+\\.?|[-+]?\\d+\\.?\\d+")){
                    txtxLow.setText(oldValue);
                }
            }
        });

        txtxHi.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue,
                                String newValue) {
                if (!newValue.matches("|[-+]?|[-+]?\\d+\\.?|[-+]?\\d+\\.?\\d+")){
                    txtxHi.setText(oldValue);
                }
            }
        });

        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {    // Проверка нажатия на кнопку
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {   // Запуск второго экрана
                if (txtf.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Пожалуйста заполните поля для ввода!");  // Проверка на заполения поля ввода txtf
                    return;
                }
                if (txtxHi.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Пожалуйста заполните поля для ввода!");
                    return;
                }
                if (txtxLow.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Пожалуйста заполните поля для ввода!");
                    return;
                }


                int a = Integer.parseInt(txtf.getText());
                double xLow = Double.parseDouble(txtxLow.getText());
                double xHi = Double.parseDouble(txtxHi.getText());
                double yLow = Double.parseDouble(txtxLow.getText());     // Считывание данных с полей ввода
                double yHi = Double.parseDouble(txtxHi.getText());
                double xMinGraph = Double.parseDouble(txtxLow.getText());
                double xMaxGraph = Double.parseDouble(txtxHi.getText());


                Axes axes = new Axes(  // Запуск класса Axes
                        900, 900,   // Размер второго экрана с графиком
                        xLow, xHi, 1,  // Параметры осей Х
                        yLow, yHi, 1  // Парамтеры осей Y


                );

                Plot plot = new Plot(  // Запуск класса Plot

                        x -> ( a * a * a) / (x * x +  a * a),  // Формула для расчета кривой


                        xMinGraph, xMaxGraph, 0.01, // Параметр начала и конца графика
                        axes // Вызов axes
                );

                StackPane layout = new StackPane( // Запуск экрана

                        plot // Вызов plot

                );


                layout.setPadding(new Insets(20));
                layout.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);");
                Stage stage = new Stage();          // Параметры второго экрана : название, цвет фона и т.д
                stage.setTitle("Верзьера Аньези");
                stage.setScene(new Scene(layout, Color.rgb(255, 255, 255)));
                stage.show();  // Вывод экрана
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(label1);
        root.getChildren().add(label2);
        root.getChildren().add(label3);


        root.getChildren().add(button);            // Вывод элементов на экран
        root.getChildren().add(txtf);

        root.getChildren().add(txtxLow);
        root.getChildren().add(txtxHi);


        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 300);   // Установка размера первого экрана

        primaryStage.setTitle("Параметры");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Axes.java

```
public class Axes extends Pane {
    private NumberAxis xAxis;  // Создание насечек на оси х
    private NumberAxis yAxis;  // Создание насечек на оси у

    public Axes(
            int width, int height,
            double xLow, double xHi, double xTickUnit,    // Объявление переменных для отрисовки осей
            double yLow, double yHi, double yTickUnit
    ) {
        setMinSize(Pane.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Pane.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
        setPrefSize(width, height);
        setMaxSize(Pane.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Pane.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);    // Размер осей

        xAxis = new NumberAxis(xLow, xHi, xTickUnit);
        xAxis.setSide(Side.BOTTOM);
        xAxis.setMinorTickVisible(false);     // Расчет оси х
        xAxis.setPrefWidth(width);
        xAxis.setLayoutY(height / 2.0);

        yAxis = new NumberAxis(yLow, yHi, yTickUnit);
        yAxis.setSide(Side.LEFT);
        yAxis.setMinorTickVisible(false);     // Расчет оси у
        yAxis.setPrefHeight(height);
        yAxis.layoutXProperty().bind(
                Bindings.subtract(
                        (width / 2) + 1,
                        yAxis.widthProperty()
                )

        );


///////////////////////////////////////////////Создание полярной сетки//////////////////////////////////////////////////

        Circle circ1 = new Circle();
        circ1.setFill(Color.rgb(255,255,255,0));
        circ1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        circ1.setCenterX(450);
        circ1.setCenterY(450);
        circ1.setRadius(65);
        circ1.setOpacity(0.3);

        Circle circ2 = new Circle();
        circ2.setFill(Color.rgb(255,255,255,0));
        circ2.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        circ2.setCenterX(450);
        circ2.setCenterY(450);
        circ2.setRadius(130);
        circ2.setOpacity(0.3);

        Circle circ3 = new Circle();
        circ3.setFill(Color.rgb(255,255,255,0));
        circ3.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        circ3.setCenterX(450);
        circ3.setCenterY(450);
        circ3.setRadius(195);
        circ3.setOpacity(0.3);

        Circle circ4 = new Circle();
        circ4.setFill(Color.rgb(255,255,255,0));
        circ4.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        circ4.setCenterX(450);
        circ4.setCenterY(450);
        circ4.setRadius(260);
        circ4.setOpacity(0.3);

        Line lin30 = new Line();
        Text angle30 = new Text();
        Text angle210 = new Text();
        lin30.setStartX(800);
        lin30.setStartY(300);
        lin30.setEndX(100);
        lin30.setEndY(600);
        lin30.setOpacity(0.3);
        angle30.setX(800);
        angle30.setY(290);
        angle30.setText("30°");
        angle210.setX(100);
        angle210.setY(590);
        angle210.setText("210°");
        angle30.setOpacity(0.3);
        angle210.setOpacity(0.3);

        Line lin30Z = new Line();
        Text angle30Z = new Text();
        Text angle330 = new Text();
        lin30Z.setStartX(100);
        lin30Z.setStartY(300);
        lin30Z.setEndX(800);
        lin30Z.setEndY(600);
        lin30Z.setOpacity(0.3);
        angle30Z.setX(100);
        angle30Z.setY(290);
        angle30Z.setText("150°");
        angle330.setX(800);
        angle330.setY(590);
        angle330.setText("330°");
        angle30Z.setOpacity(0.3);
        angle330.setOpacity(0.3);

        Line lin45 = new Line();
        Text angle45 = new Text();
        Text angle225 = new Text();
        lin45.setStartX(150);
        lin45.setStartY(150);
        lin45.setEndX(750);
        lin45.setEndY(750);
        lin45.setOpacity(0.3);
        angle45.setX(150);
        angle45.setY(140);
        angle45.setText("135°");
        angle225.setX(750);
        angle225.setY(740);
        angle225.setText("315°");
        angle45.setOpacity(0.3);
        angle225.setOpacity(0.3);

        Line lin45Z = new Line();
        Text angle45Z = new Text();
        Text angle315 = new Text();
        lin45Z.setStartX(150);
        lin45Z.setStartY(750);
        lin45Z.setEndX(750);
        lin45Z.setEndY(150);
        lin45Z.setOpacity(0.3);
        angle45Z.setX(150);
        angle45Z.setY(730);
        angle45Z.setText("225°");
        angle315.setX(750);
        angle315.setY(140);
        angle315.setText("45°");
        angle45Z.setOpacity(0.3);
        angle315.setOpacity(0.3);

        Line lin60 = new Line();
        Text angle60 = new Text(); 
        Text angle240 = new Text();
        lin60.setStartX(570);
        lin60.setStartY(150);
        lin60.setEndX(320);
        lin60.setEndY(780);
        lin60.setOpacity(0.3);
        angle60.setX(570);
        angle60.setY(140);
        angle60.setText("60°");
        angle240.setX(300);
        angle240.setY(770);
        angle240.setText("240°");
        angle60.setOpacity(0.3);
        angle240.setOpacity(0.3);

        Line lin60Z = new Line();
        Text angle60Z = new Text();
        Text angle300 = new Text();
        lin60Z.setStartX(330);
        lin60Z.setStartY(150);
        lin60Z.setEndX(580);
        lin60Z.setEndY(780);
        lin60Z.setOpacity(0.3);
        angle60Z.setX(330);
        angle60Z.setY(140);
        angle60Z.setText("120°");
        angle300.setX(580);
        angle300.setY(770);
        angle300.setText("300°");
        angle60Z.setOpacity(0.3);
        angle300.setOpacity(0.3);

        CheckBox check = new CheckBox("Отобразить полярную сетку");  //CheckBox для отображение сетки

        check.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(newValue){
                    getChildren().addAll(circ1,circ2,circ3,circ4,lin30,lin30Z,lin45,lin45Z,lin60,lin60Z,angle30,
                            angle30Z,angle45,angle45Z,angle60,angle60Z,angle210,angle225,angle240,angle300,angle315,angle330);
                }else{
                    getChildren().removeAll(circ1,circ2,circ3,circ4,lin30,lin30Z,lin45,lin45Z,lin60,lin60Z,angle30,
                            angle30Z, angle45,angle45Z,angle60,angle60Z,angle210,angle225,angle240,angle300,angle315,angle330);
                }
            }
        });

/////////////////////////////////////////////////Конец отображения//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // Подпись осей
        Text txtY = new Text();
        txtY.setX(450);
        txtY.setY(yLow);
        txtY.setText("Y");

        Text txtX = new Text();
        txtX.setX(905);
        txtX.setY(450);
        txtX.setText("X");

        getChildren().setAll(xAxis, yAxis, txtY, txtX,check); // Отображение элементов на экране
    }

    public NumberAxis getXAxis() {
        return xAxis;
    }

    public NumberAxis getYAxis() {
        return yAxis;
    }
}
```

Plot.java

```
public class Plot extends Pane {

    public Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100,450,10,10);  // Создание прямоугольника
    public PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition(); // Параметр анимации
    Polyline pol = new Polyline(); // Создание пути анимации
    public Plot(
            Function<Double, Double> f,
            double xMin, double xMax, double xInc,  //Объявление переменных для постройки кривой
            Axes axes
    ) {
        Path path = new Path();
        path.setStroke(Color.RED.deriveColor(0, 1, 1, 0.6));  // Создание кривой
        path.setStrokeWidth(2); //Толщина кривой

        double x = xMin;
        double y = f.apply(x);   // Создание переменных для отрисовки кривой
        pol.getPoints().clear();  // Отчистка анимации
        path.getElements().add(
                new MoveTo(
                        mapX(x, axes), mapY(y, axes)  // Построение трактории кривой
                )
        );

        x += xInc;

        while (x < xMax) {
            y = f.apply(x);

            path.getElements().add(
                    new LineTo(
                            mapX(x, axes), mapY(y, axes)  // Отрисовка кривой
                    )
            );
```

[image: img]